# How to create and join group in Android XMPP Multi User Chat using Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am trying to make Multi User Chat for my application. I had done the coding for single user communication and it works fine. I am unable to create or join group in multi user chat. Below is my code.

```
public class MyXMPP {

public static boolean connected = false;
public boolean loggedin = false;
public static boolean isconnecting = false;
public static boolean isToasted = true;
private boolean chat_created = false;
private String serviceName = "", hostAddress = "";
public static XMPPTCPConnection connection;
public static String loginUser;
public static String passwordUser;
XmppService context;
public static MyXMPP instance = null;
public static boolean instanceCreated = false;
private static ChatHandler chatHandler;
private MultiUserChat mMultiUserChat;
private MultiUserChatManager manager;

public String roomName = "new";
public String serverName = "conference.";

public MyXMPP(XmppService context, String mServiceName, String mHostAddress, String loginUser, String passwordUser) {
    this.serviceName = mServiceName;
    this.hostAddress = mHostAddress;
    this.loginUser = loginUser;
    this.passwordUser = passwordUser;
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public static MyXMPP getInstance(XmppService context, String mServiceName, String mHostAddress, String user, String pass) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyXMPP(context, mServiceName, mHostAddress, user, pass);
        instanceCreated = true;
    }
    return instance;

}

public org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat Mychat;

ChatManagerListenerImpl mChatManagerListener;
MMessageListener mMessageListener;

String text = "";
String mMessage = "", mReceiver = "";

static {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // problem loading reconnection manager
    }
}

public void init() {
    mMessageListener = new MMessageListener(context);
    mChatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListenerImpl();
    initialiseConnection();
}

private void initialiseConnection() {

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(serviceName);
    config.setHost(hostAddress);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

}

public void disconnect() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void connect(final String caller) {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            if (connection.isConnected())
                return false;
            isconnecting = true;
            if (isToasted)
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                caller + "=>connecting....",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            Log.d("Connect() Function", caller + "=>connecting....");

            try {

                connection.connect();

                ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
                reconnectionManager.setEnabledPerDefault(false);
                reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();

                DeliveryReceiptManager dm = DeliveryReceiptManager
                        .getInstanceFor(connection);
                dm.setAutoReceiptMode(AutoReceiptMode.always);
                dm.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceiptReceived(final String fromid,
                                                  final String toid, final String msgid,
                                                  final Stanza packet) {

                    }
                });

                connected = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("(" + caller + ")", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                Log.e("(" + caller + ")",
                        "SMACKException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                Log.e("connect(" + caller + ")",
                        "XMPPException: " + e.getMessage());

            }
            return isconnecting = false;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}

public void login() {

    try {

        connection.login(loginUser, passwordUser);
        Log.i("LOGIN", "Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");


                // Call to create Multi User Chat Group
                join();    

    } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private class ChatManagerListenerImpl implements ChatManagerListener {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                            final boolean createdLocally) {
        if (!createdLocally)
            chat.addMessageListener(mMessageListener);

    }

}


public int sendMessage(String senderID, String mMessage) {

    if (!chat_created) {
        Mychat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(senderID, mMessageListener);
        chat_created = true;
    }
    final Message message = new Message();
    message.setBody(mMessage);
    message.setStanzaId(String.format("%02d", new Random().nextInt(1000)));
    message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
    try {
        if (connection.isAuthenticated()) {
            Mychat.sendMessage(message);
            return 1;
        } else {
            login();
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {

        Log.e("xmpp.SendMessage()", "msg Not sent!-Not Connected!");
        return 0;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("xmpp Message Exception", "msg Not sent!" + e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }

}

public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {
    @Override
    public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Connected!");
        connected = true;
        if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {
            login();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        if (isToasted)

            Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionCLosed!");

        System.out.println("-------------ConnectionCLosed!----------------");
        instance = null;
        connected = false;
        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionClosedOn Error!");
        connected = false;
        instance = null;
        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Reconnectingin " + arg0);

        System.out.println("----------prem Reconnectingin----------------" + arg0);

        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionFailed!");
        connected = false;
        instance = null;
        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {

        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionSuccessful");
        connected = true;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
        Log.d("xmpp", "Authenticated!");
        loggedin = true;

        ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addChatListener(
                mChatManagerListener);

        chat_created = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }
}

private class MMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener {

    public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(final org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat chat,
                               final Message message) {
        Log.i("MyXMPP_MESSAGE_LISTENER", "Xmpp message received: '"
                + message);

        if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat
                && message.getBody() != null) {
            System.out.println("-----------xmpp message-------------" + message.getBody());

            // Here I am receiving messages which would be handled later
        }
    }

}


public boolean join(){
  try {
        MultiUserChatManager multiUserChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        MultiUserChat multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(roomName + "@" + serverName + ServiceConstant.XMPP_HOST_URL);
        multiUserChat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void processMessage(Message message) {
                Log.i("MyXMPP_MESSAGE_LISTENER", "Xmpp message received: '"
                        + message);


            }
        });

       // Getting Error at the below line. 
       multiUserChat.createOrJoin(loginUser);

      return true;


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

I am getting XMPP error when trying to execute the above code while calling the **join()** function.

Error at **multiUserChat.createOrJoin(loginUser)** this place.

> XMPPError: remote-server-not-found - cancel at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:220)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:311)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:400)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:376)

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The problem is that I was using the wrong parameter


`MultiUserChat multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(roomName + "@" + serverName + ServiceConstant.XMPP_HOST_URL);`


I am supposed to use **XMPP service name** here instead of **XMPP host url**. The code worked well when I replaced the **XMPP_HOST_URL** with **XMPP_SERVICE_NAME**


MultiUserChat multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(roomName + "@" + serverName + ServiceConstant.XMPP_SERVICE_NAME);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing the jabber ID correctly while creating the multi user chat(getMultiUserChat). The way jid is created is roomName@conferenceServername/resourceId. You need to check what should be the the conference server name that needs to be appended while creating JID. This can be done either by checking the configuration at server side or using [item discovery feature](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#items) if conference is used as separate component in XMPP side.

Answer (score 0):

For group chat you need to prepend "conference." with service_url.

Sample Code:

```
final MultiUserChatManager multiUserChatManager = 
             MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(abstractXMPPConnection);
final MultiUserChat multiUserChat = 
             multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(
             JidCreate.entityBareFrom(groupChatRoomName + 
                          "@conference." + SERVICE_URL));
multiUserChat.create(Resourcepart.from((groupChatRoomName))
               .getConfigFormManager()
               .submitConfigurationForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create room and add member to room example : Refer joinChatRoom(String userName,String roomName) function for room creation and joining.

  http://keepnote.cc/MUCGroupCreation